# Powershell export-excel working with sheets

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to autofit columns in sheet1 using following code.

```
$Userlijst | Export-Excel $ExportUsersXLS -autofilter  #-WorksheetName "Sheet1"
$excel = $exportusersxls
write-host "xlsx : " $excel
$sheet = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Sheet1']
write-host "Sheetname : " $sheet
foreach ($c in 1..9) {Set-ExcelRange -Address $sheet.Column($c)  -AutoFit }
Export-Excel -ExcelPackage $excel
```

The output errors :

xlsx :  c:\scripts\DepartmentUsers.xlsx
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\scripts\Get-Departments-Users.ps1:46 char:1

- $sheet = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets['Sheet1']
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
  ```

Sheetname :
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\scripts\Get-Departments-Users.ps1:48 char:23

- ... h ($c in 1..9) {Set-ExcelRange -Address $sheet.Column($c)  -AutoFit }
- ```
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Your variable `$excel` is just a string (path to excel file)..

Comment: @Theo ok and now what pls?

Comment: `$excel` should be the result of `Import-Excel`